# VBA Exact Match of String

Tags: xml, vba, excel, dom, xml-parsing

I'm trying to only return two authors: "Ralls, Kim" and "Boal, John". The problem is that "Ralls, Kimberly" also matches my criteria. Is there a way to set an 'exact' item match so that I can avoid this?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<book id="Adventure">
   <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
   <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
   <price>44.95</price>
</book>
<book id="Science-Adventure">
   <author>Ralls, Kimberly</author>
   <title>Midnight Rain</title>
   <price>5.95</price>
</book>
<book id="Adventure">
   <author>Boal, John</author>
   <title>Mist</title>
   <price>15.95</price>
</book>
<book id="Mystery">
   <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
   <title>Some Mystery Book</title>
   <price>9.95</price>
</book>
</catalog>
```

Using this code:

```
Sub mySub()

Dim XMLFile As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim Author As Variant
Dim athr As String, BookType As String, Title As String
Dim AuthorArray() As String, BookTypeArray() As String, TitleArray() As  String
Dim i As Long, x As Long, j As Long

Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
Dim n As IXMLDOMNode
Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set XMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
XMLFile.Load ("vba.xml")


x = 1
j = 0

Set Author = XMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book/author")
For i = 0 To (Author.Length - 1)
    ReDim Preserve AuthorArray(0 To i)
    ReDim Preserve BookTypeArray(0 To i)
    ReDim Preserve TitleArray(0 To i)
    athr = Author(i).Text
    BookType = Author(i).ParentNode.getAttribute("id")
    Title = Author(i).ParentNode.getElementsByTagName("title").Item(0).nodeTypedValue

If athr = "Ralls, Kim" or athr = "Boal, John" Then

    AuthorArray(j) = athr
    BookTypeArray(j) = BookType
    TitleArray(j) = Title

    j = j + 1
    x = x + 1
End If
Next



Range("A3:A" & UBound(AuthorArray) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(AuthorArray)
Range("B3:B" & UBound(BookTypeArray) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(BookTypeArray)
Range("C3:C" & UBound(BookTypeArray) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(TitleArray)


End Sub
```

Comment: if it passes name check you could also check length so both name and length have to match.

Comment: What makes you think it's not working?  "=" *is* an exact compare.  Neither of these return TRUE:

    If athr = "Ralls, Kimberly" = "Ralls, Kim" Then MsgBox "1"
 
    If athr = "Ralls, Kim" = "Ralls, Kimberly" Then MsgBox "2"

Comment: You could use VBA's `strComp()` which allows you to compare strings.  Try something like `If strComp(athr,"Ralls, Kim",0) or strComp(athr,"Boal, John",0) Then... `

Also, whenever I try to compare strings, with '=' or 'strComp()', I `trim()` then string, just to make sure no white space exists that could throw off the comparison.  `athr = trim(athr)`

Comment: @CarlKevinson I was losing my mind until you pointed this out. I'm working with a much larger file and could not go line-by-line for each output. Thank you for the sanity check.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one more straightforward implementation based on your code, it might be helpful.

```
Sub mySub()

    Dim XMLFile As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim colBooks As Variant
    Dim AuthorArray() As String, BookTypeArray() As String, TitleArray() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long

    Cells.Clear
    Set XMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    XMLFile.Load ("C:\Test\vba.xml")

    Set colBooks = XMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book[author='Ralls, Kim' or author='Boal, John']")
    k = (colBooks.Length - 1)
    ReDim AuthorArray(0 To k)
    ReDim BookTypeArray(0 To k)
    ReDim TitleArray(0 To k)
    For i = 0 To k
        AuthorArray(i) = colBooks(i).getElementsByTagName("author")(0).Text
        BookTypeArray(i) = colBooks(i).getAttribute("id")
        TitleArray(i) = colBooks(i).getElementsByTagName("title")(0).Text
    Next

    Range("A1:A" & UBound(AuthorArray) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(AuthorArray)
    Range("B1:B" & UBound(BookTypeArray) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(BookTypeArray)
    Range("C1:C" & UBound(BookTypeArray) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(TitleArray)

End Sub
```